# Getter/Setter method error. Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, oop

I get the following error:

> Line 13, cannot find symbol - System.out.println(getDirection(room1)); (with an arrow pointing to room1).
>   Symbol: Variable room 1
>   location: class ArtRecord.

Essentially what the code is trying to do is, go to the method of `getDirection`. And get the direction of room1 which was set in the `setDirection`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArtRecord
{
    public static void main (String[] param)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        createandprintsart();
        String location = askwhere();
        if (location == "Room 1"){
            System.out.println(getDirection(room1)); //#ERROR FOUND ON THIS LINE
        }
    }

    public static void createandprintsart()
    {
        Art room1 = new Art();
        Art room2 = new Art();
        Art room3 = new Art();
        Art room4 = new Art();

        //System.out.println(getDirection(room2));
        room1 = setDirection(room1, "To your left is a painting by");
        room2 = setDirection(room2, "Ahead of you is a painting by");
    }

    public static String askwhere()
    {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What room are you in?");
    System.out.println("Room 1");
    System.out.println("Room 2");
    System.out.println("Room 3");
    System.out.println("Room 4");
    String locationvalue = reader.nextLine();
    return locationvalue;
    }

    public static void doStuff(Art room)
    {

    }


    public static Art setDirection(Art room, String direction)

    {
        room.direction=direction;
        return room;
    }    

    public static String getDirection(Art room)

    {
        return room.direction;
    }

}

class Art
{
    String direction;
    String artist;
    String title;
    int year;
    int height;
    int width;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: @c650 Could you elaborate please.

Comment: @c650 It won't compile, so how will `println`'s help?

Answer (score 1):

`room1` is defined as a local variable in `createandprintsart()`. Thus, it is not accessible from your `main` function. Instead, you could make the rooms `static` instance variables, perhaps?

Also, note that you should not compare strings with `==`, but rather with `String.equals(String str)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I go about making the rooms into static instance variables?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I go about making the rooms into static instance variables?

Comment: Omg, Im so bad at using this website. @c650. Thanks for the answer. How do I go about making the rooms into static instance variables?

Comment: You can declare them as `private Art roomX` at the top of your `ArtRecord` class. Also, you may want to use a `private Art[] rooms` (an array) to simplify your problem. Also, you should make your `Art` class's instance variables private and use methods to manipulate them. @Haque

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. One you are trying to access the object `room1` which is not present in the scope of function `main()`. So the `Art` class objects have to be declared in class scope. Secondly the `Art` class objects also have to be static in order to be accessed from `main` function.

Finally you cannot compare strings in java using `==` operators. You have to use `.equals` and you can also avoid creating `scanner` objects for every function by moving it to class score.

```
class ArtRecord {

    static Art room1;
    static Art room2;
    static Art room3;
    static Art room4;
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] param) {
        String next = reader.next();

        createandprintsart();
        String location = askwhere();
        if (location.equals("Room 1")) {
            System.out.println(getDirection(room1)); //#ERROR FOUND ON THIS LINE
        }
    }

    public static void createandprintsart() {
        room1 = new Art();
        room2 = new Art();
        room3 = new Art();
        room4 = new Art();

        //System.out.println(getDirection(room2));
        room1 = setDirection(room1, "To your left is a painting by");
        room2 = setDirection(room2, "Ahead of you is a painting by");
    }
    ...
}
```